# Let $\Lambda(x)=(\lambda_1x_1,\lambda_2x_n,...)$ be an operator $l_2 \to l_2$. Show its range is closed iff $\inf_{\lambda_k\not=0} |\lambda_k|>0$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\Lambda(x)=(\lambda_1x_1,\lambda_2x_n,...)$ be an operator $l_2 \to l_2$. Show its range is closed iff $\inf_{\lambda_k\not=0} |\lambda_k|>0$.

I proved the backwards direction. If $x_n$ is Cauchy in $Range(\Lambda)$ then $\Lambda(y_n)=x_n$, $y_n$ is cauchy and so its limit will converge to the limit of $x_n$. I am having trouble proving the forward direction. I think it should be done by contradiciton. We assume the range is closed and yet there is a subsequence of $\lambda_k$ cinverging to $0$. I was not succcesful in

Comment: Hint: Use the open mapping theorem.

Comment: @MaoWao I wanted to do that, but note the domain may not be $l_2$ we do not assume the sequence is bounded.

Comment: You can use the domain with the graph norm (I assume you take the maximal domain of $\Lambda$, otherwise you should clarify).

Comment: @MaoWao Yes, I am using maximal domain, can you elaborate on the graph norm?

Comment: The graph norm is $\|\cdot\|+\|\Lambda \cdot\|$. It is not to hard to sow that the domain of $\Lambda$ with this norm is complete (i.e. $\Lambda$ is closed).

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Let $M$ be the closed subspace generated by $\{e_i: \lambda_i \neq 0\}$ where $(e_i)$ is the standard orthonormal basis. (Note that $M$ consist of the sums $\sum_{\lambda_i \neq 0} a_ie_i$ with $ \sum |a_i|^{2} <\infty$).  Let $\Lambda_1=\Lambda |M$. Show that range of $\Lambda_1$ is also closed and that $\Lambda_1$ is also injective. By open mapping theorem its inverse is continuous so there exist a constant $C$ such that $\sum_{\lambda_i \neq 0} |\lambda_i x_i|^{2} \geq C \sum |x_i|^{2}$ for all $(x_i)$. From this the conclusion follows immediately.

Comment: Why is the range of the restricted operator also closed?

Comment: If $\Lambda_1 x^{(n)} \to y$ then $\Lambda x^{(n)} \to y$ so there exists $x$ such that $\Lambda x=y$. Now let $x=\sum x_ie_i$ and $\Lambda x= (\sum_{i: \lambda  \neq o} \lambda_i x_i  e_i)=\Lambda_1 (\sum_{i: \lambda_i  \neq o} x_i e_i)$. Hence $y=\Lambda_1x'$  where $x'=\sum_{i: \lambda_i  \neq o} x_i e_i$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Dont you assume that $\lambda_i$ is a bounded sequence? Otherwsie $\Lambda$ is not continuous.

Comment: @2132123 Yes, I think it is implicitly assumed that $\Lambda$ is a bounded operator which is equivalent to $(\lambda_n)$ being bounded.